# The specified Android SDK Build Tools version is ignored in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

My flutter project was working properly, but when i tried to start the project recently, i got the android error below.

> WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (25.0.0) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (26.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.1.
>   Android SDK Build Tools 26.0.2 will be used.
>   To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
>   :app:properties FAILED
>   1 actionable task: 1 executed
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   *What went wrong:
>   null value in entry: outputFile=null
>   * Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

I checked my `app/build.gradle` file but could not find `buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'`.My `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` are both 27.

I tried adding `buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'` , `27.0.3` and `28.0.1` which have already been installed, but i still get the same `25.0.0` error.
I can't tell what i'm doing or did wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: Same. ```FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Android dependency 'com.android.support:support-v4' has different version for the compile (25.2.0) and runtime (26.1.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Finished with error: Gradle build failed: 1```

Answer (score 0):

Really dumb suggestion, but have you tried a File->Invalidate Caches/Restart?

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this bit:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
*What went wrong:
null value in entry: outputFile=null
```

This likely has to do with updating the Gradle version in the project (perhaps unintentionally by click the "Upgrade gradle now" button), which caused  a different parse of your Gradle script due to some form of backwards incompatibility.

If the project has source code control this would be pretty easy to check.